# In perl Pass value to another script and get

Tags: perl

I'm using the following code in perl script to call another script with argument.

The following code is to call another script

```
script1.pl

    system("start $script_name $from $range1");
```

The following code is to get the argument value

```
script2.pl
$from =shift;
$to = shift;
```

but i don't get any value in using this method. How to pass value to another script and how to get those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `system("start $script_name $from $range1");`

Use like following

```
system("start perl $script_name $from $range1");
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

*script1.pl:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system("./script2.pl 1 2");
```

*script2.pl:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$from = shift @ARGV;
$to = shift @ARGV;
print "$from $to\n";
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? did you try to run the examples I wrote?